# O marquee foi descontinuado no HTML5?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Se sim, qual a *tag* que posso utilizar para usufruir de suas funções?

Como posso limitar o início e o seu fim, exemplo: 
Ao utilizar a *tag* *marquee*, na transição de imagens ou textos sempre fica um enorme espaço entre o fim e o inicio!

Answer (score 6):

Segundo a [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0) sim e já faz certo tempo. O CSS [**marquee style**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/) deve ser usado em seu lugar.

Algumas demonstrações:

- [Vertical Marquee](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/h7SYp/)
- [Horizontal Marquee](http://jsfiddle.net/MaY5A/1/)

```css
.marquee {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px orange dashed;
}

.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}
.marquee span:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

.microsoft {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    font: 16px 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.vanity {
    color: pink;
    text-align: center;
    font: .75em 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica;
}

.vanity a, .microsoft a {
    color: blue;
    transition: color .5s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/prefixfree.js"></script>
<p class="microsoft marquee">
    <span><a href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52508/6454" >O marquee foi descontinuado no HTML5?</a> ~ Stack Overflow</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Do link: *Development of the marquee features of CSS has been abandoned.*

Comment: @bfavaretto Realmente. O site [html-5.com](http://www.html-5.com/changes/deprecated/marquee-tag.html) deve estar um pouco desatualizado. Ele foi *abandonado* em 2014, e por enquanto não há alternativas segundo o que li, então ainda é uma alternativa usável. Tem até uma discussão sobre isso [aqui](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/deprecated-elements-or-not/28016).