# Alternativa ao marquee com evento que dispara ao terminar

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

O `marquee` foi descontinuado e a alternativa é implementar um `css` para realizar o mesmo efeito de rolagem de texto, o que é válido.

Porém surgiu uma necessidade de obter o momento em que a rolagem do texto chega ao fim, evento que era presente no `marquee` por meio do `onfinish`, é possível obter o evento usando `css` e `jQuery`?

Comment: Pergunta duplicada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11862/como-fazer-um-marquee-sem-a-tag-marquee

Comment: @WallaceMaxters essa não é duplicata, aqui o AP quer um evento dentro do marquee, é o que titulo não foi intuitivo, mas ele quer algo como `onfinish`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma lib jQuery simples é https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee

Basta chamar `$("seu seletor(es)").marquee();` dentro de `$(function() {...})` ou `$.ready(function() {...})` e aplicar `overflow: hidden;`:

> Pra pausar use `pauseOnHover`, pra pegar o evento use o `bind("finished", function() {...})` no elemento

```js
$(function() {
     $('.box1, .box2').marquee();

     $('.box3').bind("finished", function() {
          console.log("Terminou!");
     }).marquee({
         "duration": 1000,
         "pauseOnHover": true
     });
});
```

```css
.box1, .box2, .box3 {
   width: 200px;
   height: 64px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.box1 {
   background: #fc0;
}

.box2 {
   background: #f0f0f0;
}

.box3 {
   background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h2>Simples</h2>
<div class="box1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit END.</div>

<h2>Pra duplicar o conteudo e dar o efeito continue</h2>
<!-- duration é o tempo que leva para terminar, quanto maior mais devagar, gab é o espaço entre as duplicatas e `duplicated` é para causar o efeito que está andando em circulos -->
<div class="box2" data-duration="5000" data-gap="10" data-duplicated="true">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit END.
</div>

<h2>Evento finished</h2>
<div class="box3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit END.
</div>
```

### API do jQuery.marquee

É possível configurar diretamente no método, assim:

```
$('seu seletor').marquee({
    //Velocidade em milesegundos
    duration: 15000,

    //Espaço em pixels entre as o elementos
    gap: 50,

    //Tempo em milesegundos antes de iniciar
    delayBeforeStart: 0,

    //direção 'left', 'right', 'up', 'down'
    direction: 'left',

    //Se true faz o elemento ser duplicado para causar o efeito de continuidade
    duplicated: true
});
```

- Lista de opções: https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee#options
- Lista de eventos (usar com `.bind` por exemplo): https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee#events
- Métodos: https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee#methods

  exemplo:

  ```
    var $mq = $('.marquee').marquee();

    $("button.playpause").click(function() {
         $mq.toggle(); //Alterna entre pausar e mover
    });
  ```

### Postagens relacionadas

- [Como fazer um marquee sem a tag <marquee\>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11865/3635)
- [O marquee foi descontinuado no HTML5?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52508/3635)

Answer (score 0):

Para aqueles que por ventura tenham a mesma necessidade, encontrei uma alternativa para o `marquee`, usando o [Jquery ScrollBox](https://github.com/wmh/jquery-scrollbox)